# BTRFS warning (device xxx): swapfile must not be copy-on-write. Why swap is activated when disabled?

Tags: swap, btrfs

I have SSD. When I check `dmesg` I see warnings and fails:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep swap
[    0.085887] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.429424] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[   35.685791] systemd[1]: Activating swap /swapfile...
[   35.690098] BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p4): swapfile must not be copy-on-write
[   35.691545] systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Swap process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
[   35.691549] systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
[   35.691934] systemd[1]: Failed to activate swap /swapfile.
[   35.691969] systemd[1]: swap.target: Job swap.target/start failed with result 'dependency'.
[   36.112620] BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p4): swapfile must not be copy-on-write
[   36.326045] BTRFS warning (device nvme0n1p4): swapfile must not be copy-on-write
```

Why system tries to activate swap if I disable it?

```
$ cat /etc/fstab | grep swap
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: @user1686: writing to fstab that there is no swapfile

Comment: Well, that's not what the fstab that you've shown says – it says that there **is** a swapfile, located at `/swapfile`. (It has no mountpoint specified, but swap entries never have one specified anyway.)

Comment: so how to disable it? I just remove that entry?

Comment: `none` does not mean "disabled", if this was what you thought. [It can be `whatever`](https://serverfault.com/a/967855).

Answer (score 0):

To really disable swapfile we should do:

> At a shell prompt as root, execute the following command to disable the swap file (where /swapfile is the swap file):
> swapoff -v /swapfile
> Remove its entry from the /etc/fstab file.
> Remove the actual file:
> rm /swapfile

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-swap-removing-file.html